# Bash: read a file contents till some pattern match and Store in another file

Tags: bash, file

I have got a text file containing some data which is separated by a dashed line. I need to store each days data in a separate file with `<filename>_yyyymmdd`.

**Input_file:**

```
01-01-2017
Some text data
--------------------------
10-10-2017
Some text data
--------------------------
```

So far I have tried is: Have some errors in the code.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$ ]] ; then; fi
done > Input_file
```

I am trying to read the date format from the file and creating a new file and appending data format to it.

Comment: try `awk -v RS='--------------------------' '{print >FILENAME"_"$1}' myfile`

Comment: @PS. OP wants filename to be `yyyymmdd` not in `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: @anubhava thanks for correcting. `awk -v RS='--------------------------' '{split($1,a,"-");print >FILENAME"_"a[3] a[2] a[1]}' myfile` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a `bash` solution then use:

```
#!/bin/bash

f="${1?needs a filename}"
while IFS= read -r line; do
   [[ $line =~ ^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$ ]] &&
   fn="${f}_${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
   [[ $line =~ ^-+$ ]] || echo "$line" >> "$fn"
done < "$f"
```

Otherwise this slightly verbose `awk` will also work:

```
awk '/^([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})$/{
   split($0, a, "-"); if (fn) close(fn); fn = FILENAME "_" a[3] a[2] a[1]} 
   !/^-+$/{print $0 > fn}' filename
```